# How to enumerate the 3rd column of a table

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

My table has 3 columns. I want to use Selenium.IE to get the element on the 3rd column. However I don't know how many rows are present. I am guaranteed that there is at least 1 row

```
[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/th[3]/span
[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/span 
[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/span
```

My Xpath looks like the above. What is the recommended approach to finding all the elements in all the rows? Should I use a "try-catch" and once an Xpath is not found, I know the last index (and text)

I am using C# with an InternetExplorerDriverService

Comment: How about without specifying the index, something like `[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/span`? That should return all rows that you can iterate through

Comment: can you please show me how the iteration would be done?

Comment: Look for examples in doc's for your xpath parser. In common it's a list/array (i'm not familiar with #C) with elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with the Xpath as mentioned by @har07

```
[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/span
```

And you can use [findElements](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_ISearchContext_FindElements.htm) to get all elements matching the xpath and iterate through them

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elements= driver.FindElements(By.XPath("[@id='content']/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/span"));

foreach(IWebElement element in elements)
{
   //do whatever with the element
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a generic function to take the table and add the logic to get the row List and ability to traverse Cells in the row.

Now you can create another list to store data of the Column by Traversing the Row till END of Table by select and store the specific CELL value from each row.

The return list will store the Value of the Column.

Example

```
 WebElement dataTable= YOUR Table Selector ( i.e Driver.findElement By your Element Identifier);
                    List<WebElement> allRows= dataTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

                        for(int rowCount=0; rowCount< allRows.size();rowCount++){
                            List<WebElement> allCells= allRows.get(rowCount).findElements(By.tagName("td"));

                        Now We can get Specific CELL Value ( In your case the CELL value will always 3 if you want to Store the 3rd column data)
                        Iterate and store the cell value from each row to a New List
```